# Какие id есть у QCalendarWidget для qss?

Tags: qt, qss

Я хочу поменять цвет каждого элемента в qss
Но пробблема в том что я не смог найти id(#) 
для этого белого блока и этих красных цыфр.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто нибудь знает названия id что бы я мог их вписать в qss

Я нашел только часть из доступных в QCalendarWidget

```
#qt_calendar_navigationbar
#qt_calendar_nextmonth 
#qt_calendar_prevmonth
#qt_calendar_nextmonth
#qt_calendar_yearbutton
#qt_calendar_monthbutton
#qt_calendar_yearedit 
#qt_calendar_calendarview
```

Comment: QCalendarWidget содержит в себе QCalendarView производную от QTableView и то что вам надо, нужно искать в видимо QTableView

Comment: @PavelGridin Я уже писал `QCalendarView, QTableView, QWidget{background:blue;color:blue;}` Но красится все кроме нужной части

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цвет заголовка в календаре можно поменять в css

```
QWidget {
   alternate-background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: точно работает, был в qt хелп и раньше не очень, а с тех пор как нокия придумали qml и на этом раззорились, совсем стал плохой

Comment: А что насчет тех красны цыфр? как поменять их цвет?

Comment: Можно поменять цвет текста вызвав setWeekdayTextFormat(), но текст поменяется не только для заголовка, а для всего месяца. Как по-другому сделать не знаю)